# Observable - Stop sequence when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an array of objects and I need to call a service that returns an observable, on each object, but I want to stop the sequence if some condition is met (e.g. service returns error).

```
const array = [
    {name: 'A', valid: true},
    {name: 'B', valid: true},
    {name: 'C', valid: false},
    {name: 'D', valid: true}
];

const fnc = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj.name);
    return of(obj.valid).pipe(delay(500));
};
```

In this case, what should be the Observable operator chain used to log only A and B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make a separate async to find out whether each item is valid you can simply use `concatMap`:

```
from(array).pipe(
    concatMap(obj => http.get(...).pipe(mapTo(obj))),
  })
  .subscribe(...);
```

You said that the service returns an error when an item is not valid so if the `http.get` call fails then `concatMap` emits an error.

However, if you want to just complete the chain without emitting an error (or if the service doesn't emit error when the item is not valid) you can use `takeWhile()`:

```
from(array).pipe(
    concatMap(obj => http.get(...).pipe(
      map(valid => {
        obj.valid = valid;
        return obj;
      }),
    )),
    takeWhile(obj => obj.valid),
  })
  .subscribe(...);
```